# AWS SES create template with lambda function always return null

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

so on my first time learning AWS stuff (it is a beast), I'm trying to create e-mail templates, I have this lambda function:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // Create createTemplate params
  var params = {
    Template: {
      TemplateName: "notification" /* required */,
      HtmlPart: "HTML_CONTENT",
      SubjectPart: "SUBJECT_LINE",
      TextPart: "sending emails with aws lambda"
    }
  };

  // Create the promise and SES service object
  const templatePromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
    .createTemplate(params)
    .promise();

  // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
  templatePromise
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      callback(null, JSON.stringify(data) );
      // also tried callback(null, data);
    }, (err) => {
      console.error(err, err.stack);
      callback(JSON.stringify(err) );
    });
```

as far as I am understanding, this function should return me a template? an object, anything? when I use the lambda test functionality I always got null in the request response

[image]
does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

edit: and It is not creating the e-mail template, I check the SES Panel - email templates and it is empty

edit2: if I try to return a string eg: `callback(null, "some success message");` it does return the string, so my guess is something wrong with the SES, but this function is exactly what we have in the AWS docs, so I assume it should just work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to resolve the Promise and change your code to just returning it as-is:

```
 return await templatePromise;
```

which should present you some more detail of what is really going wrong in your code - it might be some hidden access issue - so you might need to adjust the role your lambda function is using. `createTemplate` on the other side should not return much in case of successful execution but just create the template.

Also try to follow the following try/catch pattern when using `async` (as described here in more detail: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/)

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    data = await lambda.getAccountSettings().promise();
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }
  return data;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! weird that they show examples using promises on aws docs...